# Deployment strategies for Asp.Net MVC app on a server behind a wall of fire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firewall, webdeploy, continuous-deployment

One of our clients absolutely insist on using their own server, but refuse to open up IP ports for automatic WebDeploy (don't ask why and how - large enterprise). Usually we have TeamCity installing WebDeploy packages as and when. But not this time -(

We have looked on Octopus Deploy, hoping to install a tentacle on their server and make it poll our server, but Octopus does not seem to work that way.

We are thinking we'll have to write some sort of service that will be polling for new versions of software and if are available, do deployment. But that seems to be a lot of work. I wonder if that exists already and we can just buy this system.

What are the ways to do automatic deployment for a server that can only initiate the connection, but can't accept connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checking out [Microsoft Release Management](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/release-management-for-microsoft-visual-studio-vs.aspx), which uses a Deployment Agent that runs on the target server to pull in the deployment packages. I've been using it for the last month, and so far I'm quite happy with it.

I think that you'll get the most out of MS Release Management when you have multiple environments (say, test, acceptance and production) that you want to deploy to in mostly the same way, and maybe want different people to approve each stage.
I wrote a couple of blog posts about [installing](http://blogs.infosupport.com/installing-ms-release-management-in-a-non-domain-environment/) and [deploying a release](http://blogs.infosupport.com/deploying-an-application-using-ms-release-management/) with MS Release Management that should illustrate how MS Release Management can be used.
You can even integrate MS Release Management with TFS, so that a TFS build automatically results in a deployment to an environment.

If you only have the production environment that you want to release to, and you don't want all the extra features that MS Release Management provides, you can also consider using Powershell DSC (desired state configuration). 
By default, it uses 'push' mode, but it can also operate in [pull mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/11/26/push-and-pull-configuration-modes.aspx), using either a webservice or file share to pull the deployment packages (i.e. .mof files) from.

-- Edit: I just read your comments about aiming for Continuous Delivery, and I would definitely recommend trying out MS Release Management first, especially if you already have the [licenses](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/how-to-buy-release-management-vs.aspx).

Comment: That looks very interesting. The only problem - it looks like it is hosted in MS Cloud. But we are talking about "Big Enterprise" and when they hear word "Cloud" they are getting a fit and start to foam from their mouth. So this solution would not fly unfortunately. I'm sure will check out these options for other projects, but will have to go with Octopus this time.

Comment: Well, it can be used in combination with the cloud, but it certainly doesn't have to be - in fact, support for Azure has only been added this year I believe. In our company, we host everything on-premise, both the Release Management server and the machines we deploy to.

Comment: oh! did not realise that it can be on-premise! certainly a worth having a look.

Comment: I wish I could split the bounty, but it is not possible. So you get accepted answer, and @lahsrah gets the bounty. Both answers are equally useful!

Answer (score 4):

Octopus Deploy should work.  it supports a polling mode.

Read more about it here: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Polling+Tentacles

Comment: O_O I was convinced that this is not possible, even found answers on Octopus forums saying tentacles never poll. This seems to be a solution!

Comment: Sorry, could not split the bounty between 2 answers, so you get the bounty and @Astrotrain gets accepted answer. Both answers are equally useful!

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just install an "updater Windows Service" using Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) to do the download, just like several billion windows PCs and Servers ?

Comment: how easy would it be to hook into that loop? never used it before, no idea how it works. Got any more info?

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382721.aspx  for BITS?

Comment: Yes, although using BITS is not neccessary for the solution, its just a nice way of configuring background downloads for your updates. Having a Windows Service poll for updates is a very common pattern for pull-deployment of updates.

Comment: So you are suggesting to build a Windows Service that does deployments? that's exactly what we want to avoid.

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting you do the same as everyone else :-). Your OP just said it seemed a lot of work, I'd disagree - its a pretty simple task, and trying to get a tool to deploy your software is likely to take as much time configuring and learning it as you are likely to take in writing your own - especially since you would have had to write the installer for your code already. Its already a solution pattern, and Microsoft shipped it as the "Updater Application Block" back in 2004 (admittedly for client applications).

Comment: I disagree. Writing a deployment tool and configuring existing product for deployments are on the different scales of magnitude. We don't have time/resources/desire to build something that can be bought and is not core of our product.

Comment: Ok, fair point. I look forward to seeing the recommendations that are put forward. Good luck with your product rollout.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a PowerShell script to download and deploy a package should be trivial enough:

```
$wc=new-object system.net.webclient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.downloadfile("your_url","your_file")
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=<your_file> -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 > DWSpackage6.log
```

I omitted the code that checks for new version. Assuming you have another URL to retrieve latest version number, that is trivial as well.

After tested the script, just use a scheduled task to run it recurringly from your client's server.

Comment: Yes and no. The script is only part of the solution. The other part is to have an infrastructure where to download from, where to keep the latest version number, how to secure the connection, maintenance, etc. Overall sums up to a pretty chunk of work that we would like to avoid

Answer (score 1):

If you can install TeamViewer on their server, you can use its VPN feature to do whatever you want. However, you have to manually connect using TeamViewer, enable the VPN, and only then you can WebDeploy. Don't know if that meets your "automatic deployment" scenario (and I guess you might not be authorized to install TeamViewer in the first place).

I suppose other VPN solutions could work as well as long as the connection is initiated from their side. Could be simpler to develop a script that opens the connection than a complete deployment tool?

Comment: That's far away from automated deployment. Currently we have to do TeamViewer sessions and it takes a lot of time and collaborations. Deployments should happen by press of a single button, nothing more.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying what you meant by "automatic" :-) In this case, would a tool like [AutoVPNConnect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autovpnconnect/) help? Can you keep a VPN open all the time or would that break their security requirements? (disclaimer: I haven't tried that tool myself)

Comment: We don't have a VPN available for us (corporation is big, remember! -) Have a look on http://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html for a quick explanation what we are after. Continuous Delivery is a good way to do software.

Comment: That's another good article about CD http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/07/skeptics-guide-continuous-delivery-part-1-business-case/